# Why is <table> content extending beyond containing BootStrap "span" and overlapping, at some resolutions?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ardave/8DR6n/3/
Full Screen JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ardave/8DR6n/3/embedded/result/

I've got these three  divs at the bottom right of the page, each containing an html table with text, and it all displays fine at most desktop resolutions.

However, when I shrink my window horizontally, or when I view it on certain mobile devices, the tables' contents overlap each other.

This problem appears just as the window is sized below 979 pixels wide, which coincides with the bootstrap-responsive.css media query for tablet size, so I'm sure this is related, but I don't know enough to figure out how or why.

The problem also coincides with the width that the navbar across the top disappears, though again, I don't know enough to say how or why.

The only other possibly useful thing I've discovered is that when the window is sized so that the problem exists, when I hover over the span or table elements in the "Elements" debugger window in Chrome, I can clearly see that the tables' columns extend past the size of the tables themselves, and past the sizes of the span4 divs that contain the tables.

I don't really want the content to overflow visibly, which I think is the current problem, however I also don't want to hide or scroll the overflow.  I'd really just like the table text to stay at a non-overlapping size until the tables/span4s are forced to respond responsively by stacking on top of each other once the screen gets too narrow.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

It seems possibly excessive, but I guess SO wants me to include the code itself rather than just the links to jsfiddle, so here goes (assume that bootstrap.css and bootstrap-responsive.css are referenced)

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3">
            <div class="well sidebar-nav">
                <ul class="nav nav-list">
                    <li class="nav-header">View All</li>
                    <li><a href="/Search/Search">View All</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span9">
            <div class="hero-unit">
                 <h1>My Site Name</h1>

                <p>Introductory stuff</p>
                <p> <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="/Home/About">About &#187;</a>

                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span4">
                         <h2>Newest Entries</h2>

                        <table class="table .table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Column 1</th>
                                    <th>Column 2</th>
                                    <th>Column 3</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                </td>
                                <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                </td>
                                <td>1/28/2013</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                </td>
                                <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                </td>
                                <td>12/4/2012</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                </td>
                                <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                </td>
                                <td>11/9/2012</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                </td>
                                <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                </td>
                                <td>10/31/2012</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                </td>
                                <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                </td>
                                <td>10/31/2012</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                </td>
                                <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                </td>
                                <td>10/30/2012</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                </td>
                                <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                </td>
                                <td>10/17/2012</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                </td>
                                <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                </td>
                                <td>10/15/2012</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                </td>
                                <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                </td>
                                <td>9/29/2012</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                </td>
                                <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                </td>
                                <td>9/21/2012</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <!--/span-->
                    <div class="span4">
                         <h2>Latest Stuff</h2>

                        <table class="table .table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Column 1</th>
                                    <th>Column 2</th>
                                    <th>Column 3</th>
                                    <th>Column 4</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                </td>
                                <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                </td>
                                <td>11/9/2012</td>
                                <td>10.0</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                </td>
                                <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                </td>
                                <td>11/7/2012</td>
                                <td>8.0</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                </td>
                                <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                </td>
                                <td>11/4/2012</td>
                                <td>10.0</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                </td>
                                <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                </td>
                                <td>10/11/2012</td>
                                <td>7.0</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                </td>
                                <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                </td>
                                <td>9/13/2012</td>
                                <td>9.0</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                </td>
                                <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                </td>
                                <td>9/6/2012</td>
                                <td>7.0</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <!--/span-->
                    <div class="span4">
                         <h2>Needing Inputs</h2>

                        <table class="table .table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Column 1</th>
                                    <th>Column 2</th>
                                    <th>Column 3</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Here's a thing</td>
                                    <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                    </td>
                                    <td>1/28/2013</td>
                                    <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Here's a thing</td>
                                    <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                    </td>
                                    <td>12/4/2012</td>
                                    <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Here's a thing</td>
                                    <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                    </td>
                                    <td>11/18/2012</td>
                                    <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Here's a thing</td>
                                    <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                    </td>
                                    <td>11/9/2012</td>
                                    <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Here's a thing</td>
                                    <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                    </td>
                                    <td>11/7/2012</td>
                                    <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Here's a thing</td>
                                    <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                    </td>
                                    <td>11/5/2012</td>
                                    <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Here's a thing</td>
                                    <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                    </td>
                                    <td>10/31/2012</td>
                                    <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Here's a thing</td>
                                    <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                    </td>
                                    <td>10/30/2012</td>
                                    <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Here's a thing</td>
                                    <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                    </td>
                                    <td>10/30/2012</td>
                                    <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Here's a thing</td>
                                    <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                    </td>
                                    <td>10/18/2012</td>
                                    <td> <a href="/stuff/stuff">Lots of stuff</a>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <!--/span-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p></p>
                <p>Here's a big blob of text!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; Some Company</p>
    </footer>
</div>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse"> <a class="brand" href="/">TheSiteName.com</a>

                <form action="/Search/Search"
                class="navbar-search pull-left" method="get">
                    <input type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Search by Name" name="SearchQuery"
                    />
                </form>
                <form ReturnUrl="" action="/Account/ExternalLogin" class="navbar-form pull-right"
                method="post">
                    <button type="submit" name="provider" value="facebook" class="logonpartialextlogin"
                    title="Log in using your Facebook account">
                        <img src="/Images/facebook.png" />
                    </button>
                    <button type="submit" name="provider" value="twitter" class="logonpartialextlogin"
                    title="Log in using your Twitter account">
                        <img src="/Images/twitter-bird-white-on-blue.png" />
                    </button>
                    <button type="submit" name="provider" value="google" class="logonpartialextlogin"
                    title="Log in using your Google account">
                        <img src="/Images/google-icon.png" />
                    </button>
                </form>
                <form action="/Account/Register" class="navbar-form pull-right" method="get">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn">Register</button>
                </form>
                <form action="/Account/LogOn" class="navbar-form pull-right" method="post">
                    <input class="span2" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="UserName" />
                    <input class="span2" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="Password"
                    />
                    <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions on SO are meant to help future visitors too. This seems too localised to me.

Comment: I would be happy to edit the question to generalize it, if someone could help me to understand the cause of the problem.

Comment: Also, if someone could provide a link to a more distilled explanation of whatever principle I'm missing, perhaps then we could close this question as a "duplicate," pointing to the better question.  But I don't know enough to identify the better question myself, and I have spent some time searching.  I was just hoping for some help from the community.

Comment: Just in case: at this line in your code:  <table class="table .table-bordered"> you have to remove the "." when you are calling your class.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I can't tell you the "Bootstrap way" to fix this, since I don't use it.  I can tell you the *why*:  Your content doesn't allow it at that breakpoint.

Because rows of tables don't wrap around (ie. all of the cells for each row must appear on the same line), there is an absolute minimum width that every given table can resize down to, which depends on things like paddings and the widest non-wrapping content for each cell.  For your tables, the smallest they can go is whatever the width of "Column", "Column", and "10/11/2012" equal out to plus 48px (8px padding on each side times 3).

The `span4`s are only allowed to be 31.49% of 724px (definition on `.container` ancestor element), which isn't wide enough to contain the tables at their smallest possible width.

My recommendation would be to not try and place all 3 tables side by side.  Your display would have to be exceptionally wide in order for it to not look cramped and not have horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 21):

I know this thread is several months old, but I also know that I really appreciate when someone posts an answer that worked for their similar situation.  Here's the way I did it in bootstrap 2 and 3.

```
.cw-table-list{
    margin:0px !important;
    table-layout:fixed;  
  }
  .cw-table-list td{
    padding-bottom: 0px !important;  
    overflow:hidden;
  }
```

Hope this helps.
Twitch

Comment: Yes this helped me, and it is responsive too! +1

Comment: `overflow:hidden;` worked for me.its the best cause this also works  with overflowing images. win!

Answer (score 10):

You can apply the style = "overflow: auto;" to put a horizontal scroll bar at your table. Thus the design will still remain responsive. Follow the code:

```
.table-scrollable{
    overflow: auto;
}
```

And use it on your parent div:

```
<div class='table-scrollable'>
```

Comment: FYI - I was getting weirdness when wanting a table-bordered column and used your example successfully with .table-bordered {... also.  Thanks, Pimentel

Comment: No need to create a new class. Just wrap the parent div in a "table-responsive" class. It does the same thing

Comment: Just in new versions of twitter boostrap.

Answer (score 3):

Assign the table's container element with `overflow: auto;` and the table itself with `table-layout: fixed;`

```
.ie-table-fix {
    overflow: auto;
}
.ie-table-fix > table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```