# content in span larger in than span itself, causing columns to not tier in a responsive layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I prevent overly large child content from breaking my responsive layouts in bootstrap?

I've got a responsive layout in bootstrap.

However I am using tables to render table content - these tables get quite large.

```
    <div class="span8">
        text
        <table class="table table-bordered">
             <th> some</th>
             <th> some</th>
             <th> some</th>
             <th> some</th>
             <th> some</th>
             <th> some</th>
             <th> some</th>
             <th> some</th>
             <th> some</th>
             <th> some</th>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="span4"> 
        text    <br/>
        <span style="background:#FF0000">text</span>
    </div>
```

What I am encountering is, that at lower resolutions, then table size is bigger than the span that the table is hosted in.

I would expect the span to "grow" in size ( at least until it span12 equivalent ), letting other spans in the row fall through to a new row, so that it would look like

```
<div class="span12">
    text
    <table class="table table-bordered">
         <th> some</th>
         <th> some</th>
         <th> some</th>
         <th> some</th>
         <th> some</th>
         <th> some</th>
         <th> some</th>
         <th> some</th>
         <th> some</th>
         <th> some</th>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="span4"> 
    text    <br/>
    <span style="background:#FF0000">text</span>
</div>
```

*but only at low resolutions*

However, what is happening is, that because the content is bigger than the span, I am simply seeing overlap.

How can I avoid this from happening?  ( see attached fiddle )

http://jsfiddle.net/uahVW/3/

Comment: Similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926577/why-is-table-content-extending-beyond-containing-bootstrap-span-and-overlapp).. basically, the table cells can not be smaller at a certain point and do not wrap.

Comment: That I understand, but I expect the 2nd span (eg the span4) to be promoted to a new line, and its not. The suggestion of "overflow:auto" is a good one, but in this case, I need to tap the 4 extra spans I have, instead of overflowing.

Comment: This is a good question.  In fact, issue remains even if you have other non-table content, for example, a very_long_non_breaking_word.  This is an interesting construction even outside of bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Source of the Behavior**

Consider the following generic HTML snippet:

```
<div class="row-wrap ex1>
    <div class="floater pane1">Some_long_text_that_is_not_breaking...</div>
    <div class="floater pane2">Some text that wraps nicely.</div>
</div>
```

and the following CSS (not Bootstrap...):

```
.row-wrap {
    outline: 2px dotted lightgray;
    overflow: auto;
}
.row-wrap .floater {
    outline: 1px dashed red;
    float: left;
}
```

Basically, `.row-wrap` block element with two floated `<div>`'s.

See the following **demo fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/T9vqg/

In **Example 1**, I specify the width in % for each `.floater`:

```
.ex1 .pane1 {
    width: 70%;
}
.ex1 .pane2 {
    width: 29%;
    margin-left: 1%;
}
```

In this case, when you shrink the window, the floating elements overlap because their widths are determined by the overall width of the containing block (`.row-wrap`) and by their definition they will always fit since the sum of widths and horizontal margins is 100%.  In this case, long non-breaking text or a table can trigger a content overflow condition.

In **Example 2**, I set the width to `auto` on one of the floating child elements.

```
.ex2 .pane1 {
    width: auto;
}
.ex2 .pane2 {
    width: 29%;
    margin-left: 1%;
}
```

In this case, you get the expected behavior, the 2nd floating elements wraps to a second line if you make the window narrow enough.

However, eventually, you can make the window narrow enough so that you will get an overflow condition regardless of how you float the elements.

**Fixing This In Twitter Bootstrap**

I have limited experience with Bootstrap.  However, I would probably set up a wide span, row container and define two generic div's within it that float to the left.  Just define some custom classes to define the behavior as illustrated in my examples.

Comment: I agree.  These CSS grid frameworks rely on floats, and floats have limitations.  Good design involves making compromises to respect the limits of the technology we work with.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're looking for, but for a responsive layout with table cells, using `display:inline-block` will push table cells that don't fit in the container to the next line. Check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uahVW/8/).

Comment: Hmm, I'm looking for something that allows the spans to resize based on contents. eg http://jsfiddle.net/uahVW/9/ should also be fixed ideally

Comment: Of course, this assumes a one-row table.  I was assuming the table would be multiple rows as in a typical data table.