# Table not respecting Bootstrap Grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a hard time trying to understand why the table I have doesn't respect bootstrap's grid system. It took me about 2 hours to isolate and be able to update the error. Please help.

I'll post the code, but I think you will understand the error more easily looking at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/alejoss/e9qhcvsw/5/) fiddle and the [full-screen](http://jsfiddle.net/alejoss/e9qhcvsw/5/embedded/result/) result. Isn't the table supposed to respect Bootstrap's grid system?

```
  <div class="col-md-8 border">
<div class = "table-responsive">
<table class = "table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Code</th>
<th>Company</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Change</th>
<th>Change %</th>
<th>Open</th>
<th>High</th>
<th>Low</th>
<th>Volume</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>AACccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc</td>
<td>$1.38</td>
<td>-0.01</td>
<td>-0.36%</td>
<td>$1.39</td>
<td>$1.39</td>
<td>$1.38</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>  
</div> <!--col-md-8-->

<div class="col-md-4 border">
    <div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-info">
        At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this answer can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14927074/4014432

Answer (score 3):

Well, it does, but you have several issues in your code:

1) You must load Bootstrap.js

2) Your table is really narrow for your columns, so yo must use a wider column or edit the cutting point

3) you can cut some of the padding to allow for more space.

4) your nowrap text doesn't help at all and it won't happen in the wild (and if so, you can force wrap)

5) You need some special code for Firefox

All that being said, I made [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dsbt1wgj/), see code below

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9 border">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-responsive">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Code</th>
                            <th>Company</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>Change</th>
                            <th>Change %</th>
                            <th>Open</th>
                            <th>High</th>
                            <th>Low</th>
                            <th>Volume</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>AACccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc asd asdasd asdasdasdads adasd asdasdasd asdasd</td>
                            <td>$1.38</td>
                            <td>-0.01</td>
                            <td>-0.36%</td>
                            <td>$1.39</td>
                            <td>$1.39</td>
                            <td>$1.38</td>
                            <td>$1.38</td>
                            <td>$1.38</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--col-md-3-->
        <div class="col-md-3 border">
            <div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-info">At vero eoset accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and **CSS** (only to fix Firefox issues as per [Bootstrap guide](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables))

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    fieldset {
        display: table-cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: I added bootstrap js to my fiddle. Still doesn't work. Thanks for your solution.. but isn't bootstrap's grid supposed to be respected by all elements inside it? ... this is why backend developers cant digest CSS. Anyway, thanks a lot Fabio.

Comment: Bootstrap (and anything and everything) will work as long as you know the boundaries, it's just a framework, not magic, and can't cover all given situations, specially if you provide a crazy situation. You can say the same about any other framework, programming language or almost anything you can think about. The beauty of Bootstrap is that it's very customizable and you can adapt it to crazy situations as well, but they aren't covered by default

Comment: Great answer! Plus, the responsive-table class is not magic, it only kicks in when the viewport hits the breakpoint, not when the column can't deal with the content

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your example is the one word first cell. The CSS does not break one word by default.
To change that add in you TD style

```
word-break: break-word;
```

Then define a percentage width for your TD

```
word-break: break-word;
width:15%;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e9qhcvsw/8/

However, be careful, bootstrap adds the following media query on small width :

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
.table-responsive>.table>thead>tr>th, .table-responsive>.table>tbody>tr>th, .table-responsive>.table>tfoot>tr>th, .table-responsive>.table>thead>tr>td, .table-responsive>.table>tbody>tr>td, .table-responsive>.table>tfoot>tr>td {
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Which will stop the word-break effect, so you need to override it or not use the table-responsive.

Finally, I would highly recommend to use a responsive grid instead of a table.